# Custom getters/setters in .NET - MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, getter-setter

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal? PotentialFutureExposure
{
    get { return STPData.MaximumCreditExposure; }
    set 
    { 
        STPData.MaximumCreditExposure = value;
        this.PotentialFutureExposureOverride = value;
    }
}

public decimal? PotentialFutureExposureOverride { get; set; }
```

So I have these two properties. Basically, I want the `PotentialFutureExposureOverride` property to return it's own value if it has one, otherwise I want it to return the value of `PotentialFutureExposure`. Now `PotentialFutureExposure` sets the override when it's set, but for some reason currently,  `PotentialFutureExposureOverride` is still returning blank even though `PotentialFutureExposure` has a value.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, `PotentialFutureExposureOverride` is null even when `PotentialFutureExposure` is non-null?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the getter for `PotentialFutureExposure` return the value of the override if there is one? That way, you don't always have to check for the override value elsewhere in code. I realize that's a bit off-topic, but sometimes getting some unrelated thing sorted helps me solve the real problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
private decimal? _override = null;

public decimal? PotentialFutureExposure
{
    get { return PotentialFutureExposureOverride ?? STPData.MaximumCreditExposure; }
    set
    {
        STPData.MaximumCreditExposure = value;
        this.PotentialFutureExposureOverride = value;
    }
}

public decimal? PotentialFutureExposureOverride 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (_override.HasValue)
            return _override;
        return PotentialFutureExposure;
    }
    set
    {
        _override = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just redundant though?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want your getter as

```
get { return PotentialFutureExposureOverride ?? STPData.MaximumCreditExposure; }
```

?

Comment: In this case, could you please provide the code for `STPData` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

PotentialFutureExposure doesn't really have a value.  In your code, STPData.MaximumCreditExposure has the actual value.  Is it possible that STPData.MaximumCreditExposure has a value before you set it in the PotentialFutureExposure setter?  If that is the case, then PotentialFutureExposure will always look as if it has a value.